# Bookmark menu with UITableview Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, bookmarks

I have the following problem. I created a fully functional browser, but when I use the "add bookmark function" or the "show bookmark function", I get always a Thread1: signal SIGABRT error. I tried everything since 8 hours and I can't find the solution. Can someone take a look at my code at give me a clue how to fix this? I'm very frustrated and hope that someone can help, because I really don't know what to do. I think it has something to do with the "forKey" tags, but I'm not sure. Here is my code:

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionary setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:@"medis"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {


}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    }

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
}

@end
```

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FavoritenController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,   UIWebViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>

{


UIWebView *Webseite;
UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
UIBarButtonItem *forwardButton;
UITextField *textField;
UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton;
NSString* urlBeforeEditing;


FavoritenController* favoritenController;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *onlinetauscher;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *Webseite;
@property ( nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem   *refreshButton;
@property ( nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *forwardButton;

- (IBAction)onlinetauscher:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

- (IBAction)pressRefresh:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

- (IBAction)zeigeMedikamente:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)hinzufuegen:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"



@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize Webseite;
@synthesize refreshButton;
@synthesize textField;
@synthesize backButton;
@synthesize forwardButton;

- (void)loadString:(NSString*)urlString{
    NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString:@"."];
    NSURLRequest* request;

    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        if ([urlString hasPrefix:@"http://"] == YES || [urlString hasPrefix:@"https://"] == YES) {
            request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        } else {
            NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@", urlString];
            request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
        }
    } else {
        NSString* tempString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
        NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.de/search?q=%@", tempString];
        request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
    }


    [Webseite loadRequest:request];

}
-(void)loadBookmark:(NSString*)urlString {
 [self loadString:urlString];
 self.textField.text = urlString;
 }
-(void)cancel {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Delegates

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)atextField { //?
    [self loadString:textField.text];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)
navigationType{

    textField.text = [request.URL absoluteString];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)awebView{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

}
-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)awebView{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    if ([awebView canGoBack] == YES){
        [backButton setEnabled:YES];
    }else{
        [backButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
    if([awebView canGoForward] == YES){
        [forwardButton setEnabled:YES];
    }else{
        [forwardButton setEnabled:NO];
    }


}
#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:0 context:NULL]; //erzeugt sigabrt
    favoritenController = [[FavoritenController alloc] init];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"index.html"];

            NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"thewebsite"];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
    if (urlData) {
        NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet");
         NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"thewebsite"];
        NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
        [Webseite loadRequest:myRequest];
    }
    else {
         NSLog(@"Device is not connected to the internet");
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    [Webseite loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
    }



    }



- (IBAction)onlinetauscher:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"index.html"];


    NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"thewebsite"];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
    if (urlData) {
        NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet");
  NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"thewebsite"];
        NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
        [Webseite loadRequest:myRequest];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Device is not connected to the internet");
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        [Webseite loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
    }

}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setWebseite:nil];
    [self setTextField:nil];
    [self setRefreshButton:nil];
    [self setBackButton:nil];
    [self setForwardButton:nil];



    [super viewDidUnload];
        }
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}


- (IBAction)pressRefresh:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self loadString:textField.text];
}

- (IBAction)zeigeMedikamente:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {


    UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favoritenController];
    favoritenController.delegatee = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    [favoritenController newMethod];
}


- (IBAction)hinzufuegen:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {


        NSString* title = [Webseite stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
     NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:title, @"title", textField.text, @"url", nil];          
     [favoritenController.medis addObject:dict];

     [favoritenController.tableView reloadData];
     UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bookmark added" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alertView show];

     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favoritenController.medis forKey:@"medis"];
}


@end
```

FavoritenController.h:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FavoritenController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray* medis;
    __unsafe_unretained NSObject* delegatee;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* medis;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSObject* delegatee;

-(void) newMethod;
@end
```

FavoritenController.m:

```
#import "FavoritenController.h"

@interface FavoritenController ()

@end

@implementation FavoritenController
@synthesize medis, delegatee;
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"medis"] count] != 0) {
            self.medis = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"medis"];
        } else {
            self.medis = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.medis = NULL;


}


- (void) cancel {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
    NSDictionary* dict = [medis objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [medis removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [medis insertObject:dict atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.medis forKey:@"medis"];

}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [medis removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.medis forKey:@"medis"];          }
}
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Meine Medikamente";
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action: @selector(cancel)]];
    medis = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"medis"] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.editButtonItem];

}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
            return YES;
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [medis count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

            cell.textLabel.text = [[medis objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[medis objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString* url = [[medis objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"];
     #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
    if (self.delegatee && [self.delegatee respondsToSelector:@selector(loadBookmark:)]) {
     [self.delegatee performSelector:@selector(loadBookmark:) withObject:url];
     }
    [self cancel];
}



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
                }
    return self;
}









- (void) newMethod{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"My Bookmarks";
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action: @selector(cancel)]];
    medis = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"medis"] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
 @end
```

debug console:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2e6a, 0x0000000104ccc002 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000104ccc002 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000104c925c5 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
    frame #2: 0x0000000104a32cec libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 129
    frame #3: 0x0000000104831051 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 257
    frame #4: 0x0000000104856ac9 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 267
    frame #5: 0x0000000101cca046 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 103
    frame #6: 0x000000010485426e libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x0000000104853ef9 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
    frame #8: 0x0000000101cc9f5e libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
    frame #9: 0x00000001021718e4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 676
    frame #10: 0x0000000105a0dad2 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #11: 0x00000001025fd610 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 171
  * frame #12: 0x00000001017c5ddf Websitemobil`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5e43c640) + 111 at main.m:14
    frame #13: 0x000000010498c92d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: What does the stack trace look like when you get the error?

Comment: I added it on the question

Comment: No, that's an assembly language representation of the code at the point of the crash.  The stack trace would show the sequence of calls that arrived there.  If you type 'bt all' in the debug console, it should print the stack symbols.

Comment: ok, sorry. This one?